# $5$ prizes are distributed among $20$ students. What is the probability that a particular student receives $3$ prizes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $5$ prizes that are to be distributed among $20$ students. What is the probability that a particular student receives $3$ prizes ?

Comment: How do you propose to start with the answer? Find the number of total outcomes first, since you are dealing with probability. Do you know  the number of total outcomes?

Comment: Depends on how they are distributed. Is it a lottery? Is there a jury that picks the winners based on who they like most? Or on how the students perform on a test? Does the jury give out one prize first and then choose the winner of the second prize only among the 19 students that do not yet have a prize, or among all 20? Does already having the first prize increase the probability of receiving the second prize since it is an easy to measure signal that the student apparently deserves prizes? It seems that all these scenarios are pretty common in the real world but they yield different answers

Comment: Also, does "a particular student receives 3 prizes" mean "a particular student receives exactly 3 prizes" or "a particular student receives at least 3 prizes"?

Comment: It was closed a few seconds before I copy and paste my answer ...

Comment: Note: for the same scenario, I got  a result different from the one provided in the only answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming prizes are uniques, each can be given out in $20$ ways. So total number of ways of distributing $5$ orizes is

$$N = 20^5$$

Now one person needs to get $3$ prizes. So we select three of them out in $5\choose3$ ways and bundle them together. This bundle can go to any student. This gives us

$$n={5\choose3}\cdot20 = 200$$

Now the other two prizes can go to any of the $19$ students left in $19$ ways each. So total is

$$n = 200\cdot19\cdot19=72200$$

Hence probability is

$$P=\frac{72200}{20^5}=0.0225625$$